# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number while running PL SQL block from nodejs

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, node-oracledb

I have following pl/sql block:

```
DECLARE
    user_name varchar(255);
    custom_exception EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA exception_init( custom_exception, -20001);
BEGIN
    SELECT name 
    INTO user_name
    FROM data_table where ID = '1';
    
    IF user_name  = 'temp' THEN 
        RAISE custom_exception;
    END IF;
END;
```

When I run it from Oracle SQL Developer, it works fine.
But I am getting ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number while running it from nodejs.

Call from Nodejs code:

```
var output = await connection.execute(fs.readFileSync('path_to_pl_sql_file', 'utf8'), {
    message: {
        dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
        type: oracledb.STRING,
        maxSize: 100
    }
}, {
    autoCommit: true
});
```

Can someone point out what going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was not with the PL/SQL block.
I was passing in bind variables while executing the PL/SQL from nodejs and that bind variable was not present in the SQL.
Hence the error!